# Mod_rewrite rules - remove folder name

Tags: mod-rewrite

I should change URLs to gain ranking on seo. Customer sent me the list of new urls(30 items). Im noobie in mod_rewrite, but today I began to read manuals

`Client side` -> `server side`

`site.com/our-solutions/business.php` -> `site.com/content/solution/bc.php`
`site.com/our-solutions/internal.php` -> `site.com/content/solution/ia.php`
`site.com/our-solutions/assess-risk.php` -> `site.com/content/why/assess.php`
`site.com/our-solutions/erm-risk.php` -> `site.com/content/why/model.php`

Etc.

could you helo me write the rules for this case? I have predefined list of urls but you can see I must to remove folder content from each URL and change the page name to desirable

Answer (score 0):

Here's what the beginning should look like:

```
RewriteRule /our-solutions/business.php /content/solution/bc.php [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule /our-solutions/internal.php /content/solution/ia.php [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule /our-solutions/assess-risk.php /content/why/assess.php [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule /our-solutions/erm-risk.php /content/why/model.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

---

I'm sorry but your question sound very like "I'm not very good, so can someone do the job for me?". I mean, just look around, you'll get a lot of answer, just get your hands dirty.

---

- Here's the wiki of [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as)
- The [howto's htaccess official guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html)
- The [official mod_rewrite guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

And if that's not enough:

### Two hints:

If you're **not** in a hosted environment (= if it's *your own server* and *you **can** modify the virtual hosts*, not only the `.htaccess` files), try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

Comment: Thank you Olivier. I just need a start point for this task because I never used mod_rewrite before

Comment: Are you on a hosted environment?